# How to prevent frequent "uncrecognized usb device" error on win10 startup?

Tags: windows-10, usb, device-manager

I'm installing win-10 on many PCs. I've noticed strange issue. I don't know what is the cause ? Some USB wireless keyboards give error on windows startup "Unrecognized USB device" and it doesn't work. Once i unplug device from USB port and re-plug it again. it works fine. But, after shutting down and starting win-10 again. It gives same issue. I tried windows update and uninstalling  then re-installing device from device manager and nothing works.The problem happened on many PCs. The PC that had this issue make same error even if changing the USB keyboard. What is the possible causes for this problem ? How to overcome it ? Thank you

Comment: Enable legacy USB in BIOS ?

Comment: @Smock Yes it is enabled